# How to fix module name conflict in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pycharm

Error creating Django application: Error on python side. Exit code: 1, err: CommandError: 'untitled1' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as a project name. Please try another name.

Answer (score 0):

which version of python are you using? upgrade your version of django or downgrade your version of python and this should solve the problem.

you can do in cl:  python --version

if you are using a newer version of python to run a project in

cl: alias python='python3'

This should work if you have the correct setup

Comment: I used you answer but it didn't work and I use The python version is 3.7 and django is 2.2

Answer (score 0):

uninstall django and delete you directories then install again you can do this on cl: pip uninstall django

then cl: pip install django

hopefully this should work